# Cannot submit the form because no form on the page currently has that name

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I have two EditForms in a Blazor Static Server Component.

I want to show 2nd EditForm when first one is submitted, and then Submit 2nd EditForm and get it's data. But upon submitting 2nd EditForm I get this error that doesn't make any sense to me.

> Cannot submit the form 'SecondForm' because no form on the page currently has that name.

Here are my two EditForms

```
@if(ShowSecondForm)
{
    <EditForm id="SecondForm" Model="SecondModel" method="post" OnValidSubmit="SecondValidSubmit" FormName="SecondForm" class="mt-4" Enhance>
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <InputText @bind-Value="SecondModel.FieldOne" class="form-control" autocomplete="FieldOne" aria-required="true" />
        <label for="FieldOne" class="form-label">FieldOne</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => SecondModel.FieldOne" class="text-danger" />
    
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
}
else
{
    <EditForm id="FirstForm" Model="FirstModel" method="post" OnValidSubmit="FirstValidSubmit" FormName="FirstForm" class="mt-4" Enhance>
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <InputText @bind-Value="FirstModel.FieldOne" class="form-control" autocomplete="FieldOne" aria-required="true" />
        <label for="FieldOne" class="form-label">FieldOne</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => FirstModel.FieldOne" class="text-danger" />

        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
}
@code {
    private bool ShowSecondForm = false;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private FirstModel FirstModel { get; set; } = new();

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private SecondModel SecondModel { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        FirstModel ??= new();
        SecondModel ??= new();
    }
    
    public void FirstValidSubmit()
    {
        //Make second form visible
        ShowSecondForm = true;
    }

    public void SecondValidSubmit()
    {
        //Debugger not hitting here
    }
}
```

I tried to add Enhance keywords to both the EditForms and tried data-permanent attribute as well, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Try it _without_ the `Enhanced` attributes and put it all inside a `<div data-enhance-nav="false">`. . I can kind of see how all these partial updates and you switching Forms can lead to a conflict.

Comment: Second option would be to put both Forms in their own component. Gives you a cleaner separation of handlers and [SupplyParameterFromForm].

Comment: @ℍℍ your first suggestion didn't work, and If I go with 2nd option then app will do a page refresh that I don't want.

Comment: I meant 2 components, not 2 pages.

Comment: Yeah I got your point, that didn't work too because it didn't make much difference.

Comment: Try removing the ids

Comment: @RBee didn't work that either

Comment: I have de same problem. You have resolved that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the right way. Try it like this:

```
@if(!ShowSecondForm)
{
    <EditForm Model="FirstModel" method="post" OnValidSubmit="FirstValidSubmit" FormName="FirstForm" class="mt-4">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <InputText @bind-Value="FirstModel.FieldOne" class="form-control" autocomplete="FieldOne" aria-required="true" />
        <label for="FieldOne" class="form-label">FieldOne</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => FirstModel.FieldOne" class="text-danger" />

        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
}

<EditForm Model="SecondModel" method="post" OnValidSubmit="SecondValidSubmit" FormName="SecondForm" class="mt-4">
    @if(ShowSecondForm)
    {
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <InputText @bind-Value="SecondModel.FieldOne" class="form-control" autocomplete="FieldOne" aria-required="true" />
        <label for="FieldOne" class="form-label">FieldOne</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => SecondModel.FieldOne" class="text-danger" />
    
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    }
</EditForm>




@code {
    private bool ShowSecondForm = false;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "FirstForm")]
    private FirstModel FirstModel { get; set; } = new();

    [SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "SecondForm")]
    private SecondModel SecondModel { get; set; } = new();

    
    public void FirstValidSubmit()
    {
        //Make second form visible
        ShowSecondForm = true;
    }

    public void SecondValidSubmit()
    {
        //Debugger not hitting here
    }
}
```

It could be that since it is Blazor Static Server, the SeconForm form is not considered if it is not rendered from the beginning